# Python | Проблемы с web view в kivy

Tags: android, python, браузер, kivy

Пробую сделать веб браузер в kivy.
Использую код, который нашел:https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-native-embedded-browser
Естественно запускаю на андроиде. В ide под названием PyDroid, где уже установлен kivy, версии 1.11.
Но получаю следующую ошибку:

> [INFO ] [Logger ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/Download/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-01-01_4.txt
>
> [INFO ] [Kivy ] v1.11.0.dev0, git-8b6af30, 20190320
>
> [INFO ] [Python ] v3.7.2 (default, Mar 20 2019, 15:02:54)
>
> [GCC 8.2.0]
>
> [INFO ] [Factory ] 184 symbols loaded
>
> [INFO ] [Image ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/storage/emulated/0/Download/t.py", line 6, in 
>   from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.7/site-packages/android/runnable.py", line 8, in 
>   from android.config import JAVA_NAMESPACE
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'android.config'

Не знаю, что делать. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

С PyDroid не получится дергать нативные вызовы из исходников. Только из APK.

Comment: А как на счет Kivy Launcher? Есть ли способ без создания apk?

Comment: Нет, забудьте, как страшный сон!

Comment: Ну что же, сильно измучевшись, я установил buildozer, kivy (в чистую виртуальную машину) и создал apk приложения. Результат очень расстроил - приложение закрылось (вылетело), естественно без никаких уведомлений. Пробовал на разных устройствах, но без успехов - нигде не работает данное приложение!!!

Comment: В spec файле в requirements указывал следующее: python3, kivy

Comment: Ошибку надо смотреть! Дебажить не пробовали?